# How to verify that the seed generated by wallet software/hardware is not BIP85 seed?

Tags: wallet, mnemonic-seed, seed, bip85-deterministic-entropy

I just learned about BIP85 today. It will generate a new seed that I don't need to back up.
I think it is pretty cool to only have to backup my one BIP39 seed and the index of BIP85.

However I started to think that this BIP85 can be used for something malicious. A wallet developer can make a wallet to generate a BIP85 seed from that wallet developer's BIP39 seed. So I wonder how can I verify the seeds that I got from some wallet software/hardware are not a BIP85 seed?

Comment: This is why you use FOSS only. And mainstream, not too new, used by millions, smart people have audited the code.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be prevented or detected.

But if you're considering the possibility that your wallet itself is under attacker control, you have bigger problems. It could just send your coins to the attacker directly, without needing to trick you into creating a backdoored seed.

Comment: So in that case... Do you think it's possible that Satoshi Nakamoto or other creators of bitcoin has that master seed of all seeds? or the master private key of all private keys in BTC? We will never know right?

Comment: If you create your own seed with honest software, you know it's not backdoored.

Comment: Yes but is it possible that there is a master key to backdoor all the seeds?

Comment: Most wallets, and certainly the only ones you should use, are open source. You can verify yourself how they're generating the seed.